# Google Map resize not working

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Im trying to show a google map with a slideToggle effect how ever the map does not show completely.

the css class has already 100% of width. How can I use resize option correctly?

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php $custom = $this->item->extra_fields; echo $custom[0]->value; ?>, <?php $custom = $this->item->extra_fields; echo $custom[1]->value; ?>),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas<?php echo $this->item->id; ?>'),
      mapOptions);

  }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#mostrarmapa<?php echo $this->item->id; ?>').click(function () {

        $('#map-canvas<?php echo $this->item->id; ?>').slideToggle();
        $('#map-canvas<?php echo $this->item->id; ?>').addClass('showmap');
    });
});

google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `resize` trigger event of your map in the callback function of your `slideToggle`.

```
$('#map-canvas<?php echo $this->item->id; ?>').slideToggle(function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

Comment: Weird thing, Ive already tried that and didnt work.

If I try to enter the command directly on console shows this: 

google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
undefined

Comment: My first assumption would be the `$(document).ready()` is run before the `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)` - so the `resize` event is triggering on a map that's not initialized yet. Move your `click` listener inside your `initialize()` function.

Comment: Thanks Suvi, I did as you said, but still not working http://goo.gl/hqEvWi Could you take a look?

Comment: I see what's happening here..you have the same global variable `var map` as reference for all 4 of your maps (which is why the last map toggles properly). You either need to make 4 separate variables or make them local inside the scope of an anonymous function.